# Limit: ratio of the digit product and the number itself

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, decimal-expansion

> Compute:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n},a,n\in\mathbb N$$ Where $a_n$
>   equals the product of the digits of $n$ in base $10$.
>
> source Math Analysis 1 exam, 2012

My attempt:
The first idea that came to my mind:
$$a_n=0\;\forall\;n,k\in\mathbb N, s.t. n=10k$$
There certainly are some convergent subsequences $(a_{p(n)})$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{p(n)}=0$$

I thought of writing $n$ either in this polynomial form:
$$n=\sum_{i=0}^nd_i10^i$$
or in Horner's algorithm:
$$\begin{align*}
n&=d_{0}+10\left(d_{1}+10\left(d_{2}+10\left(d_{3}+\cdots+10\left(d_{k-1}+10 d_{k}\right) \cdots\right)\right)\right),\\
k&=\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1
\end{align*}$$
(In my country we denote Briggs logarithm with $\log$)

The first option seemed better.

Then I decided to express $a_n$ this way:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}d_i$$
I got this: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}d_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^nd_i10^i}$$
but I stuck here not knowing how to write a concise proof. Is there a better way of solving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:  for a number with $k$ digits, $a_n \le 9^k$ while $n \ge 10^{k-1}$

Comment: Is the squeeze theorem suitable in this case?

Comment: @Praskovya2.718281828 Yes, it is

Comment: @RossMillikan, is it: $$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}10\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^k=0$$

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya:  That is correct.